# Greek letters in italic in math equation

Tags: symbols, italic

I use `\Pi` and `\Sigma` in my math equations however, they are not printed in italic like other text. I guess this is because they are symbols and not really text. Putting `\textit` into the equation has no effect at all. Is there a way to italic these symbols?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`amsmath` defines the uppercase greek to follow math alphabet switches:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$a +\Sigma + \Pi$

$\mathit{a +\Sigma + \Pi}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: note that the shape of the `\mathit` `a` is *not" the same as if it's just an ordinary math `a` (this is true for computer modern, but it may not be for other fonts).  `\mathit` is ordinarily used for italic *words* in math environments; single letters are assumed to be variables so the style is adjusted slightly. in this way, a math variable `a` can be distinguished visually from the article "a" in english; in other languages, other single letters sometimes have non-mathematical semantics.

Comment: `\mathnormal` will do here as well for the Greek letters and typeset an ordinary math `a`

Answer (score 22):

If you *always* want the uppercase Greek letter in italics, the easiest method is to load `amsmath` and change the meaning of `\Gamma` and similar commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\Gamma\varGamma
\let\Delta\varDelta
\let\Theta\varTheta
\let\Lambda\varLambda
\let\Xi\varXi
\let\Pi\varPi
\let\Sigma\varSigma
\let\Upsilon\varUpsilon
\let\Phi\varPhi
\let\Psi\varPsi
\let\Omega\varOmega

\begin{document}
$\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi
\Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If instead you need both varieties, then input the italic ones with the `var` prefix: `\varGamma` and so on.

Note that some font packages, notably `kpfonts` and `fourier`, allow for options that decide whether using by default italic Greek uppercase in math.

Comment: @Josh [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) When you have enough reputation, don't forget to upvote answers that helped you- it rewards those that looked at your question with 10 reputation points :)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I'm still getting an upright gamma for `\Gamma` and an italic gamma for `\VarGamma`. Is there a new solution, to fix that via options of `amsmath`? Do I have to defeine all my `let` commands after `\begin{document}` (which I think quite annoying)?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Please, make a new question with all that's needed to understand the problem. The minimal example above works, so you must have a different set up for your document.

Comment: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124697/32245]

Comment: What would I do if I wanted a non-italic Greek letter in math mode?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Look at the `upgreek` package.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks much! Very easy package to use, to be sure.