# How can I set uppercase greek letters as italic in math mode by default?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, italic, greek

This is a follow up question to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87240/32245).

The recommended solution doesn't work for me. I therefore let all my mathematical packages in the MWE. The result is an upright Psi followed by an italic Psi. I would like to have all upper-case Greeks being italic in formulas. The possibility to set one character upright (for a constant, an operator...) would be great. Therefore I wonder, if there is a more beautiful solution around.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{fontenc}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\Gamma\varGamma
\let\Delta\varDelta
\let\Theta\varTheta
\let\Lambda\varLambda
\let\Xi\varXi
\let\Pi\varPi
\let\Sigma\varSigma
\let\Upsilon\varUpsilon
\let\Phi\varPhi
\let\Psi\varPsi
\let\Omega\varOmega
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[
per-mode=symbol-or-fraction,
locale=DE,
sticky-per
]{siunitx} 
\usepackage{xfrac}
%
\begin{document}
$\Psi \varPsi$
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**  My knowledge over the used math-packages is quite small. Don't know, if I use them at all (`amssymb` and `mathtools`). If they are obsolete or not recommended for typesetting in Germany (English and German) or if something is missing for typical formula setting, I would be glad for every advise.

Comment: The package `luatextra` interfers...

Comment: You have to load `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`, while `luatextra` loads it without that option.

Comment: if you need a single upright greek cap, before redefining the name of that letter, do something like this: `\let\upPsi\Psi`, then do your reassignment for the new default: `\let\Psi\varPsi`. then you can ask for `$\upPsi \Psi$`.

Comment: `[no-math]{fontspec}` before `luatextra` works fine. Is that an answer or just a workaround? Should I report the interference anywhere?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi There's nothing to report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice is to use `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  per-mode=symbol-or-fraction,
  locale=DE,
  sticky-per
]{siunitx}

\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}
$\Psi \symup{\Psi}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that the default is slanted, but with `\symup` you can get the upright letter.

---

With `unicode-math` you don't need `amssymb`. Load `mathtools`, if you want it, in place of `amsmath` *before* `unicode-math`.

Don't load `commath`: it is buggy.

---

*Note*: in the previous version of the code `\mathup` was used, but `unicode-math` underwent some changes and now `\symup` is the command to use for this purpose.

Comment: 1. would you mind a personal recommendation: mathtools vs. amsmath? 2. how do you set operators like differential, derivative or partials? (no commath) 3. `Package unicode-math Error: Cannot be run with pdfLaTeX` (with LuaLaTeX I get over hundret errors...)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi If you load `luatextra` you're running LuaLaTeX; if you get errors, you probably have an outdated TeX distribution. About `mathtools` vs. `amsmath`: it's a false problem, because the former loads the latter; if you need the features of `mathtools`, then load it. For `commath`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120379/4427 and you won't use it any more.

Comment: I will contact MikTeX or see, if there are newer versions. Updates are all installed (MikTeX 2.9). Your MWE only compiles with XeLaTeX. Thanks for your explanations and the help. Commath has been dismissed from my cluttered header.tex

Comment: Ulrike Fischer already reported it here: http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2276

Comment: Did someone succeed with this? I am still getting \um_set_mathcode:nnn errors although the MiKTeX maintainer "fixed" that a while ago. Unicode-Math is not working with LuaLaTeX for me.

Comment: Works now with a fresh installation of MiKTeX and a change from 64 bit to 32 bit installation. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This does not work for me with `lualatex` (the second `\Psi` does not appear). Is `lualatex` not fully supported by `unicode-math` or do I just have to add something to the MWE?

Comment: @schtandard The answer was working in 2013; now `\symup` should be used instead of `\mathup`.