# Conflict between option ISO of package txgreeks and \mathcal

Tags: math-mode, fonts, incompatibility

When I use the package option `ISO` to make Greeks italic, I find that `\mathcal` is out of work. Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etex} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[ISO]{txgreeks} 
\begin{document} 
$\mathcal{O}/\mathcal{P}$ 
\end{document}
```

You can see the difference when you keep or delete the `\usepackage[ISO]{txgreeks}`.

Comment: Package `txgreeks` is an addendum for package `txfonts`, which indeed changes many math fonts. If you want to have uppercase Greek math letters in italics, then see question [Greek letters in italic in math equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87238/greek-letters-in-italic-in-math-equation).

Comment: The package `txgreek`, with or without `ISO`, uses a different font for `\mathcal`.

Comment: My aim is twofold: the first one is to make all Greeks such as $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ italic, the second one is to use \mathcal which should appear normally. Strangely if I don't use ISO, all Greeks,  no mather they are uppercase or lower case, are upright.

Comment: I do not understand. `\mathcal` is not out of work here. And if I do not use `ISO`, the lower case Greeks are still italic. You should minimize your code as much as possible, show some picture of what you see and explain, what you want to have. "Out of work" does not give good information on your problem especially as you are changing the fonts here. First `amsfonts`, then `txgreeks` (`txfonts`). What do you want to have?

Comment: As far as I can see the answer of egreg for the cited [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87238/greek-letters-in-italic-in-math-equation) answers your request perfectly. No TX fonts with their changed `\mathcal`. Math Greek upper case letters are made italic by the code in the answer. And the lower case letters are italic by default.

Comment: I cannot understand why the output of the lower case letters in my tex is not italic.

Answer (score 2):

That the math font for `\mathcal` changes, when package `txgreeks` is loaded, is not an incompatibility, but intended behavior, the [abstract](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/txgreeks/txgreeks.pdf) of package `txgreeks`:

> The TX Fonts 1 of Young Ryu provide a very complete replacement for
>   the default math fonts of TeX and LaTeX, containing all CM symbols and
>   even all symbols from the AMS fonts, and more. In particular upright
>   shapes for the Greek letters are available (they are necessary in
>   French mathematical typography). The `txgreeks` package allows LaTeX
>   users who use the TX fonts to easily select the shapes (italic or
>   upright) for the Greek lowercase and uppercase letters. This is
>   compatible with using arbitrary text fonts in the document.

Thus it is not a surprise, that `txgreek` loads package `txfonts`, which enables the TX fonts for math, including the font for `\mathcal`.

The CM/AMS fonts are using italic for lower case Greek letters by default. The remaining task to get italic upper case Greek letters is 
discussed and answered in question "[Greek letters in italic in math equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87238/16967)".

This is a modification of egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87240/16967). It changes the macro definitions of `\var<GreekLetterName>` with `\GreekLetterName`. The upright symbols are not lost, but available with prefix `var`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\@for\@tmp:=Gamma,Delta,Theta,Lambda,Xi,Pi,Sigma,Upsilon,Phi,Psi,Omega\do{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\@@tmp\csname\@tmp\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname\@tmp\expandafter\endcsname\csname var\@tmp\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname var\@tmp\endcsname\@@tmp
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Lowercase Greek letters in italics}
\[\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\dots
\]
\subsection*{Uppercase Greek letters}
\subsubsection*{Italics}
\[\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi
\Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega\]

\subsubsection*{Upright}
\[\varGamma \varDelta \varTheta \varLambda \varXi \varPi
\varSigma \varUpsilon \varPhi \varPsi \varOmega\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: It seems that $\gamma, \delta$ are still not italic.

Comment: @ksj03 They are definitely *not* upright in the image in my answer. Update the MWE with the correct font settings you are using.