# I want to make the `\Sigma` become italic type

Tags: math-mode

I want to get a italic type `\Sigma`, just like[image],but if I can use `\mathit` to get it.
This is my code.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\Sigma$$
a
$$\mathit{\Sigma}$$
b
\end{document}
```

Hope that someone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add some useful information, if use `\mathit`, `\Sigma` will disappear

Comment: Unrelated: don't use `$$...$$` this is not LaTeX syntax.

Comment: @daleif Ok, I will modify them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is. Do you want `\Sigma` to give the italic version without having to type `\mathit`?

Comment: @campa yes, I just want to get italic type `\Sigma`, but I don't know to get it.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87240/82917

Comment: @campa Thank you very much