# \mathit Greek letter will disappear when loading fontspec package

Tags: fontspec

I found an answer of `\mathit` Greek letter: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87239/180617

However I found `\mathit` Greek letter will disappear when loading `fontspec` package, even  if no command like  `\setmainfont`

Here is my mwe:

```latex
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document} 
$a +\Sigma + \pi$

$\mathit{a +\Sigma + \pi}$
\end{document}
```

will output

[image]

If I comment `\usepackage{fontspec}`, it will output

[image]

with both `xelatex` and  `pdflatex`

Why will this happen?

Comment: note that `\mathit` is the _text_ italic font used in math, so the input `\mathit{a +\Sigma + \pi}` is rather unexpected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log will show

```
Missing character: There is no ^^F (U+0006) in font [lmroman10-italic]:mapping=
tex-text;!
```

as `fontspec` sets up `\mathit` to expect Unicode encoding but `\Sigma` (unless you load `unicode-math`) will expect to find Sigma in the legacy 7-bit TeX encoding position.

You can use

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
```

so that `fontspec` leaves the math setup untouched, or you could use `unicode-math` and `\symit{\Sigma}` to use Unicode fonts throughout.